# HP Photosmart C7200 Series is not getting wireless signal to print

Tags: printer

The printer is set up on a wireless router and has always worked fine with my HP laptop.  My laptop still shows that the print request was sent to the printer and it shows it as "Printing" then it shows "Error" on the Printers Status page.  The printer itself shows no error messages but never shows that it receives the print request.  The router itself is working...my laptop is connecting with it.

Any ideas?  Thanks!